# Unique maximizer

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I have two functions, $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. $x\in[0,X]$ while $y\in [0,Y]$. Both functions are non-negative on the domain.

Further, $f$ is increasing in $x$ and decreasing in $y$. $g$ is the opposite, increasing in $y$ and decreasing in $x$.

In addition, I have $f(0,y)=0,\forall y$ and $f<1,\forall (x,y)$.

And $g(X,y)=0 \forall y$,$g(x,0)=0 \forall x$ and $g(x,y)<M y$ for some real number $M(x)$.

Define $V(x,y) = f(x,y) \cdot g(x,y)$. I want to prove the existence of unique maximizer of $V(x,y)$ or if I need further assumption to make it happen?

One of the example of V is

$$V(x,y) = P(x,y) \cdot y(X-x)$$

$P(x,y)$ belongs to $[0,1]$ and increasing in $x$ decreasing in $y$.

Looks trivial but want to know how to show it.

Thanks a lot!